# $(1-\cos(2x))^2$ = $(\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)-(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))^2$

Tags: derivatives

How does one instantly know that

$$(1-\cos(2x))^2$$

leads to

$$(\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)-(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))^2$$

I know that

$$\cos(2x) = \cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^2$$

but it confuses me that I can't get to what's written above.

I got it from here (see denominator):

[image: i]

Comment: [$\cos^2x + \sin^2x = 1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Pythagorean_identities).

Comment: @an4s Ah now I see. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, in fact: $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ and $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$

So, substituting, I obtain: $$(1-\cos(2x))^2=(\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)-(\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x))^2=(2\cos^2(x))^2=4\cos^4(x)$$

Comment: I believe it's actually $\cos(2x)=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$...

Answer (score 1):

$$(\cos^2x + \sin^2x-(\cos^2x-\sin^2x))^2=(1-\cos2x)^2$$ 
$$\cos^2x + \sin^2x=1$$ and 
$$\cos^2x -\sin^2x=\cos2x.$$